# Andorra , the 90/180 count down

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, andorra

Can anybody say if i spent a few days in Andorra does my time there count towards my 90 days , does the count down stop and restart when i leave. As I understand the count starts the day your foot touches French /Spainish soil and the day your foot leaves its last impression on the French /Spanish soil, both are counted. So if i spent a week in Andorra the day i left France is counted and the day i returned is counted, so for the week in Andorra 7 days for my schengen 90 days I save 5 days to spend in France so i can take my time driving to Calais.

Comment: The dates of the exit/entry stamps is what counts. If both dates are the same: 1 day. If you have no stamps: then you never left and all the days count.

Comment: @MarkJohnson if a traveler in the Schengen area obtains a departure stamp and an arrival stamp on the same day then there are 0 days outside the Schengen area, not 1.  In fact, the same is true if the arrival stamp is dated on the day after the departure stamp.  To interrupt the counting of Schengen presence, there must be at least one entire calendar day during which the traveler was absent from the Schengen area.  So, to calculate days of absence between two stamps, subtract the dates and then subtract 1. For example, departure on August 1st and return on August 10th means 8 days of absence.

Comment: @phoog The stamps determin the amount of days spent **inside** the Schengen Area. That is all that the border guards are interested in and the only thing they will calculate.

Comment: @MarkJohnson yes, but if a Schengen visitor has entered and exited Andorra and somehow manages to get stamps in both directions, there will be three relevant stamps in the passport, and a reader might reasonably assume that "both stamps" in your comment refers to a stamp showing departure from the Schengen area to Andorra along with a stamp showing arrival in the Schengen area from Andorra.